# XForms editor(designer) for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, xforms

I am looking for Xforms editor to Eclipse. I found something information (click), but still without result. Is possible to find source of Visual XForms Designer(now it's  IBM Forms)  might somewhere source still exists? Any sugest how create/edit XForm in Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no usable XForms editor on the market that you can use to target multiple XForms engine. Some XForms engine come with an XForms editor, specifically tailored for the XForms engine they come with. In particular:

- [IBM Forms](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/lotus/products/forms/) comes with IBM Forms Designer, an Eclipse-based tool.
- [Orbeon Forms](http://www.orbeon.com/) comes with Forms Builder, a web based tool.